# Virtual install OS with computers hardware

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine, virtualization

Can i install an OS so it would have the same drivers as the host computer?

So, then i could create a backup from the OS and just revert it to my hostcomputer.
Could this work ? (or any alternatives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can sort of work. I have used a disk image program then used that image to create a VM, but all virtualiztion products I have used create their own virtual hardware so what really happens is when you first boot the image in a VM it will go through hardware detection and install drivers - at that point it is no longer a match to the machine the image came from - but the old drivers are still available in the image. I use VirtualBox and [Image for Windows](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/image-for-windows.htm) but a simple way to try your idea out is to use a MS tool [Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) and then use VirtualPC (free). making a disk image is a good way to do a system back up - you could look also at clonezilla if you just want to use a disk image to do a backup.

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldn't work and it won't work.
Basically you emulate some hardware. You just can't use the exact same stuff.
(Maybe XEN? Beats me)